Using Case When expression as variable withing another Case When expression?
I have a complex SQL query where one of the Case When expressions is:
Lead Type
case 
    when (LHSTM_Rating.prev_rating is null AND LHSTM_ReEngaged.prev_status = 'Rejected') then 'Re-Engaged'
    when (LHSTM_Rating.prev_rating is null AND (LHSTM_ReEngaged.prev_status <> 'Rejected' OR LHSTM_ReEngaged.prev_status IS NULL)) then 'New Lead'
    when LHSTM_Rating.prev_rating = '3' and (case when (MDL.lead_rating = '0' OR (MDL.lead_status = 'Converted' AND OPP.opportunity_id is not null)) then '0' else MDL.lead_rating end) = '2' then 'Nurture Journey'
    when LHSTM_Rating.prev_rating in ('3', '2') and (case when (MDL.lead_rating = '0' OR (MDL.lead_status = 'Converted' AND OPP.opportunity_id is not null)) then '0' else MDL.lead_rating end) = '1' then 'Nurture Journey'
    when LHSTM_Rating.prev_rating in ('3', '2', '0') and (case when (MDL.lead_rating = '0' OR (MDL.lead_status = 'Converted' AND OPP.opportunity_id is not null)) then '0' else MDL.lead_rating end) = '0' then 'Nurture Journey'
    else 'Re-Engaged' 
    end as 'Lead Type',

This uses a combination of criteria from original table and other complex sub-queries that are joined onto the original table.
It works fine in the context of the existing query but now I need to incorporate it as a condition into another Case When expression, as the outcome of that Lead Type query can have an influence on how we determine the value of another column.
Is there a way to avoid having to specify above multiple times such as below?
Lead Sub-Type idea:
case when 

(whole Lead Type statement) = 'Re-Engaged' then ....

when 

(whole Lead Type statement) = 'New Lead' then ... else ... end as 'Lead Sub Type'


If you are only testing for equality, you can do case (whole Lead Type statement) when 'Re-Engaged' then .... when 'New Lead' then ... else ... end.

Note that those are case expressions (not statements).

Put the case thing into a cross apply and then you can refer to it anywhere in the query
